# Deleting a line of a text file

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, text-files

So, I am attempting to delete a file from a numbered text file. Each entry after \n is a new number. I was attempting to take the file, store each line in a string, and then make a new file by omitting the unwanted line and fprinting the rest. Unfortunately, pointers are giving me trouble. It deletes one, and returns the other one in the proper location but not with the proper string or returns a blank file.

```
fp=fopen("data.txt", "r+");
fpo=fopen("out.txt", "w");

printf("Please enter number of the student whose data you would like to delete.\n");

scanf("%d", &i);

while(fgets(str, 128, fp)){
    if((atoi(str)!=i))
    {
        fputs(str, fpo);
    }
}
fclose(fp);

fp=fopen("data.txt","w");

while(fgets(str, 128, fpo)){
    if((atoi(str)!=i))
    {
        fputs(str, fp);
    }
}
fclose(fp);

fclose(fpo);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have is superfluously complex (and doesn't work with large files, and wastes memory). Why don't you just copy the file line-by-line, and simply *not copy* then one you want to exclude?

```
FILE *f_in = fopen("infile.txt", "r");
FILE *f_out = fopen("outfile.txt", "w");
// ...error checking comes here...

char buf[LINE_MAX];

while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, f_in)) {
    if (!(/* omission condition here */)) {
        fputs(buf, f_out);
    }
}

fclose(f_in);
fclose(f_out);
```

Comment: Ok, that does seem much simpler. However, if the condition is its location in the stream how could I handle that? Simply if buf[1]!=i where i is the number of the line?

Comment: @user2414507 No, but think about that. (you don't want to compare the `i`th character, because it doesn't make sense.)

Comment: @user2414507 If that's the case, and you have less than 10 lines, then you can do that by writing `if (buf[0] - '0' != i)` ('0' is not the same as 0, and 1 is the second character of the string since array indices start at 0). However, I suppose you rather want to convert the line number to an `int` instead. Use `strtol()` for that purpose.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that I need to keep it in the same file. So the snippet of code I have now is above. Also, I used atoi since I do not understand strtol ().

Comment: @user2414507 Don't use `atoi()`, it's horrible. Use `strtol(string_to_convert, NULL, 0)`. Well, to keep the line in the same file, you can simply delete the old file and rename the new file when you're done.